# Post-install re-start returns to Live USB

Tags: system-installation

After installing Ubuntu with a Live USB (erasing the previous OS in the process), I got the post-install message stating that the computer should be re-started. However, merely re-starting takes me to the Live USB again because, to prepare for the install, I had set the BIOS to boot into USB first. Yet I couldn't eject the Live USB before re-starting. I tried shutting down after the installation, turning on, setting the BIOS to boot from the HD, but I was still greeted by the Live USB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the following options:

- Change the BIOS settings to not boot from USB at all.
- Remove the USB during the reboot. You should have a second or two when the power to the computer (and therefore also the USB) is off. Simply unplugging it at this time is safe.
- Shut down the computer (if you have that option), then remove the USB, then power the computer back on.